# Compare a date pointer with a date

Tags: c, arduino

In an Arduino script how do I compare a date pointer with a string that is a date. Currently I am trying:

```
while(year(t)=="1970") {  
    getTime();
   }
```

but I am getting a can't compare a pointer with a string compiler error which I understand but I would like to compare the two somehow and the somehow is where I am stuck. Thanks for any help for this newbie

Comment: are you asking how to de-reference a pointer?  like this `year(*t)`

Comment: you obviously are also new to programming in general - it is _very_ advisable to learn programming basics first - without that knowledge you will probably never achieve your goals. The above snippet will loop forever, effectively deadlocking the microprocessor.

Comment: Arduino code is not written in C.

Comment: `year()` and `getTime()` are not part of the standard Arduino API. You should state which libraries you are using and, more importantly, what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @unwind horribly wrong, every _sketch_ is a c program, being compiled by gcc into hex-code - you get a IDE for C together with very powerful and comfortable libraries.

Comment: @specializt: it’s actually C++.

Comment: How is `year()` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(year(t)==1970)
{
    getTime();
}
```

year() returns 4-digit year integer. not a string.

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks! Learned something.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing strings should be done using `strcmp()` not with `==` operator

You are actually comparing the pointers and not the strings by using `==`

Answer (score 0):

I would import `<string.h>`
Then use `strcmp()` to compare the two strings:

In your case

```
if (strcmp(string1,string2) == 0) {
  //Some good stuff :)
}
```

C does not support direct comparison between strings.
This because strings are `char` arrays and should be manipulated properly

Usually, a for loop is required to make a proper comparison, but in this case it is much easy using a library function, that does the exact same thing

Just to let it know, to compare you would use something like

```
for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++) {
  //Loop till end of string
  //Check if every char of string 1 is equal to the one in the same position of string 2
}
```

Hope this was helpful.

Best regards.